# Launching an activity from background service only when app is in foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-video-player

I have a background Service which runs every 5 seconds and upon receiving a certain successful response from my backebnd it will launch an Activity to play a video. My problem is when the app runs in the background and my service gets called and receives a successful response and I am not sure how to handle the video playing part knowing that my app is running in the background. Is there any way to schedule the video playing part to when my app goes back in foreground mode?

Comment: Can you please show us some code? BTW, you want the background service to start your app (even when it's closed)?

Comment: That service only should launch the video activity when the app is in foreground otherwise if it's in background wait for user to display the app in foreground

Answer (score 0):

Instead of launching an `Activity`, you can send a broadcast `Intent`. Your `Activity` can listen for the broadcast `Intent` while it is in the foreground and in the background. If the `Activity` gets the broadcast `Intent` while it is resumed (on screen in the foreground), it can react immediately. If it gets the broadcast `Intent` while it is paused (in the background), then it can save the information locally, and then in `onResume()` it can check if a broadcast `Intent` was received while it was paused and then act accordingly.